# « Foutez le camp »?

Tags: expressions

Ma question se pose sur l'expression « Foutre le camp ! », qui veut dire « Partir d'ici ! ».

En me demandant d'où ça venait, je me suis dit que « foutre » venait d'une expression du langage parlé voulant dire « mettre » et que « le camp » était utilisé dans le sens de campement. Seulement voilà, « mettre un campement » signifie « s'installer », ce qui a une signification totalement opposée à celle de « foutre le camp ».

Est-ce qu'il y a une faille dans mon raisonnement ? D'où vient cette expression ?

Comment: Il semblerait qu'il n'y ait aucune réponse certaine à cette question. Je me suis tout de même demandé si ça ne venait pas éventuellement de « Je ne veux pas de toi ici, fous le camp là-bas ! »

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Le camp vient bien du campement, et à l'origine l'expression « lever le camp » est celle qui correspond au départ. Pourquoi « ficher » et « foutre » sont ensuite venus se substituer à « lever », par contre…

Note que d'après la [définition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/camp) de camp, Valéry posait déjà cette question à Gide en 1927 !

Comment: Alain Rey (Dictionnaire historique de la langue française) n'a pour une fois pas grand chose à ajouter...
« Ficher le camp  *planter son camp*  a pris (1752) la valeur plaisante de *s'en aller* (sans combattre, sans payer, puis de s'enfuir. »
Tout serait dans la valeur plaisante, alors.  Par antiphrase ? 
À noter que Claude Duneton n'est pas d'accord avec A. Rey : http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/foutre-ficher-le-camp.php

Comment: J'ai accepté ta réponse comme « Il n'y a pas de réponse ». Dommage, j'aurais bien voulu pouvoir connaitre la vraie raison…

Comment: Amertume de l'aporie...

Answer (score 0):

Fot el camp.  C'est langue catalane.

Comment: Quelles sont tes sources ?

Comment: Et quelle est la signification ?